# How to invoke the click of "x" on a form

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, events

Is there a way to invoke (by code) the click event of the "x" on the top right corner of a Form? To be "as if" a user clicked on that?

Ps. I don't want a function that does `this.Close()`

I read the other answer, but It seems that `Application.Exit(); Application.ExitThread(); Environment.Exit();` aren't showing a different behaviour.

In particular, my application works like this:

```
Main
{
    using (Form1 f = new Form())
    {
        f.Show();
    }

    using(Game1 game = new Game1())
    {
        // Create game
        game.Run(); //Xna Framework
    }
    // Do something
}
```

Note that I don't see the code of `Run()` because it is inside the Xna Framework.

Ok, inside my game, in a function I want to exit from it letting `Run()` to return.

If I do:

```
this.Exit(); // Game.Exit()
```

Or the other three possibilities above, the Whole application closes and `//Do something` isn't executed.

BUT, if I press the "x" on the window of the game, it works.

I can't understand why and I can't understand how to reproduce the "x" click programmatically.

Comment: What's wrong with `this.Close()`?

Comment: @Enigmativity It has the same effect than doing this.Exit()

Comment: Are you just wanting to close the form without closing the application?

Comment: You can't close the form without closing the application. The form holds open the message loop. When you close the form the message loop closes and so too does the application. You need to create a second form if you want to be able to close it.

Comment: @Enigmativity I have a static main in which other forms are created, abd when I close them they Return as expected, they don't let the whole Application shut down.

Comment: Yes, that's what is expected. The "root" form, if you want to think of it that way, holds the app open. Child forms do not. You can close as many child forms as you like, but close the "root" form and the app closes.

Comment: I don't know if I understood correctly your answer, but I want to say that I don't call the .Run() from the "form"! I call it inside static main in Program.cs

Answer (score -1):

You could send the WM_CLOSE message to your window handle. This would involve using native winapi calls.

See: [send message to a window handle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/713371/send-message-to-a-window-handle)